# Hide a column in ASP.NET Dynamic Data

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

Is there any way to apply an attribute to a model file in ASP.NET Dynamic Data to hide the column?

For instance, I can currently set the display name of a column like this:

```
[DisplayName("Last name")]
public object Last_name { get; set; }
```

Is there a similar way to hide a column?

**Edit**: Many thanks to Christian Hagelid for going the extra mile and giving a spot-on answer :-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Had no idea what ASP.NET Dynamic Data was so you promted me to so some research :)

Looks like the property you are looking for is

```
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
```

There is also a similar property for tables

```
[ScaffoldTable(false)]
```

[source](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2008/05/15/DynamicDataWebsitesScaffoldTableScaffoldColumnAttributes.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A much, much easier method: If you want to only show certain columns in the List page, but all or others in the Details, etc. pages, see [How do I hide a column only on the list page in ASP.NET Dynamic Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80175/how-do-i-hide-a-column-only-on-the-list-page-in-asp-net-dynamic-data)

Simply set AutoGenerateColumns="false" in the GridView control, then define exactly the columns you want:

<Columns>
    ...
    <asp:DynamicField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" />
    <asp:DynamicField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />
</Columns>