# ScaffoldColumn(false) not working because it is a FK

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

[image]

I am using ASP.NET Dynamic Data. The page dynamically creates a `List`, `Edit`, `Details` pages to display the records stored in the table in the DB.

I have the `Sub Contractors` in the table but I want its visibility set to false on screen.
I've tried

```
[HideColumnIn(PageTemplate.List)]
[Display(Name = "SubContractor Id", Order = 70)]
public object SubContractorId { get; set; }
```

ALSO:

```
[ReadOnlyColumnIn(PageTemplate.List)]
```

But no joy. Iv made these changes in the `database.cs` file.
Anyone know how can I make it disappear or remove the hyperlink from it?

**EDIT:**

`[ScaffoldColumn(false)]` usually works but because `SubContractorId` is a FK it seems to not take effect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide a column in ASP.NET Dynamic Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25653/hide-a-column-in-asp-net-dynamic-data)

Comment: looked at it but because sub contractor is a FK, it doesn't have the effect as it should with  [ScaffoldColumn(false)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the possibility of using **Custom pages** (List and other) for your Dynamic Data site which allows you hide specific fields.

For more information: [How to: Customize the Layout of an Individual Table By Using a Custom Page Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488537%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)