# Data Driven Website - how to hide specific columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, field, data-driven

We have a datadriven website in C# being built in VS 2010. How do I prevent certain columns in a table from being displayed on the webpage ?

Comment: Are you using GridView to display data?

Comment: Please check the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25653/hide-a-column-in-asp-net-dynamic-data

Comment: thanks, Garrison. This post referred to solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not display the table itself, display **views**. This usually makes for a better design.

You can show or hide columns in views as you wish.